# Removing special characters from csv file

Tags: python, csv

FYI: New to python. I have a csv file **(with {','} as a delimiter)** that has some sensor data. There is a heading with just a hyphen {**'-'**} that occurs many times that is not required. Since it does not correspond to any data, it causes the data columns to shift and hence not match with the column heading. To resolve this, after looking through the internet, I do this:

```
specials = '\'-\''
new_line = str.replace(line, specials, '')
```

This replaces the hyphen with nothing. However now it is a blank space and the issue is not resolved. If I do this:

```
specials = ',\'-\'' #see the , added
new_line = str.replace(line, specials, '')
```

nothing happens i.e. even the hyphen {**'-'**} is not removed. Probably this is due to the {**','**} being the delimiter. Apart from changing the delimiter (assuming it would work), how can I remove the extra heading that pops up in the first row and causes the mismatch between data and heading? It is clear that by just making any exact sequence {**,'-'**} removed solves the issue for me but I am not able to do it.

Please ask if unclear.

Edit: Here is the complete code

```
import csv
import sys

output_file = open('sensor_data.csv', 'w')
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as input_file:
    data = csv.reader(input_file)
    writer = csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv. QUOTE_ALL)

# special characters to be removed
specials = ",'-'"

for line in data:
    line = str(line)
    new_line = str.replace(line, specials, '')
    writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Put in a good csv file with **{,}** as delimiter and put an extra **{-}** as heading without adding corresponding column data (so you have one more heading than the columns with data).

Comment: for line in data:

        line = str(line)

        new_line = str.replace(line, specials, '')

        writer.writerow(new_line.split(','))

Comment: do it this way and see if it works. data is obtained using csv.reader() with the file as input

Comment: Use `"` to declare strings containing `'`, you won't have to escape them and it will be clear

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything for me. I tried " with and without \

Comment: can't you remove the extra `,'-'` prior to reading the file with the csv reader? Depending on how many files you're dealing with, do it by hand or with a multi-file search/replace?

Comment: manually not possible because I want to automate it and use it for further processing...I don't know if I can open it as a txt file and find something but as I see it this is equivalent to searching for specific characters and replacing it, isn't it?

Comment: If the `-` isn't needed at any other time during the lifespan of these files, I would just write a little script that batch edits the files to remove the extra characters (or, if you control the process that generates the files in the first place, find out where the `-` is being added and get rid of it!).

Comment: I guess that would be my approach. Its just that we have already a lot of data and if they are to be used this has to be resolved. I'll try the batch edits but I am still curious as to why this doesn't work. Seems straightforward

Comment: `new_line = str.replace(line, specials, '')` does not work because `replace()` replaces *strings* and you are regarding `specials` as a *set* of characters you want replaced by nothing. Use `str.translate()` instead: it works the way you are expecting `replace()` to work.

Comment: @BoarGules Correct me if I am wrong but str.translate uses output of str.maketrans(). In this case, str.maketrans() only does mapping 1-on-1. So it individually removes all characters **,** along with what I desired...

Comment: `translate()` has a second parameter that specifies characters you want removed. If you don't want to do it that way then delete the unwanted characters individually `.replace("-","").replace("'","")` etc

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to copy/paste a few sample lines from your CSV file? It would then be easier to suggest a possible solution. Also then show what the output for that data should look like.